# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat' has no attribute 'v1' Tensorflow v: 1.10.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I got that error when I'm trying to train my model:

```
(tensorflow1) C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection>python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 52, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 35, in <module>
    from object_detection.models import faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor as frcnn_inc_res
  File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\models\faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor.py", line 30, in <module>
    from nets import inception_resnet_v2
  File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\slim\nets\inception_resnet_v2.py", line 375, in <module>
    batch_norm_updates_collections=tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS,
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat' has no attribute 'v1'
```

Tensorflow version: 1.10.0

I'm using conda virtualenv created with:

```
conda create -n tensorflow1 pip python=3.5

(tensorflow1) conda install tensorflow-gpu
```

Working on Windows 10

Comment: I am having the same issue... If you figured it out would love to know the solution

Comment: @Dick It was a problem about my tensorflow version, v1 is from tensorflow 2.0, so you have to rewrite the code or use a earlier version

Comment: Thanks... I have been using tensorflow 1.9 because that is what the tutorial I am following is using. However... looks like the models must have been updated to use tensorflow 2... Arg... Only descent tutorials I can find seem to be for 1, and things are upgrading to 2... bit of an awkward time.  Will try downgrading the model.

Comment: @Dick have a look to this tutorial, it has a video and in the repo has all the specific versions and commit it uses from the Tensorflow repo. https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10

Comment: Having the same issue, working on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @Loren Thanks for the tip. Will give that tutorial a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the Comment Section for the benefit of the community.

This code `tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` is not available on `Tensorflow==1.10.0`

If you are using an older version of TensorFlow, [here](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10#2a-download-tensorflow-object-detection-api-repository-from-github) is a table showing which GitHub commit of the repository you should use.

To have those features update your version to `1.15` or `2.2` as below

```
   conda install tensorflow=1.15
```

or

```
   conda install tensorflow=2.2
```